# How can I combine record results in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, find

So I have two separate queries:

```
tagged_items = Item.tagged_with(params[:s], :on => :tags)
searched_items = Item.find(:all, :conditions => ["MATCH(title) AGAINST (? IN BOOLEAN MODE)", "*#{params[:s]}*"])
```

The first `tagged_items` is using the `acts_as_taggable_on` plugin to find all the items tagged with XYZ.

The second, `searched_items`, is used to search the `items` table for the search term.

So, how could I combine (and avoid duplicates) the results of these two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items = (tagged_items + searched_items).unique
```

But it would be much better if you could fetch them with single query.

Answer (score 2):

Check out named_scope. The second query can be converted to named_scope easily, I'm not sure about the first one, but if you can rewrite it using find, you're home.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NamedScope/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 0):

This approach...

```
@items = tagged_items | searched_items
```

...would make more sense if you're looking to use the results of these queries in a View, instead of working with an Array, and accomplishes the de-duplication as well.